# Why is Rails 3.2.2 Generating URLs prefixed with /assets when using redirect_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Well the title Question pretty much sums it up, But I'd like to detail a scenario anyways,

I've created a DemoController, (I have not created a Resource model), and my **routes.rb** looks like this:

```
DispatchMe::Application.routes.draw do
  root to: "demo#index"
end
```

From the demo controller I'm dong the following:

```
class DemoController < ApplicationController
  def index
    redirect_to :action => 'show'
  end

  def show
  end
end
```

There is a file in: **app/views/demo/show.html.erb** of course, And I'd expected that template to be rendered but instead I'm getting the following error:

**ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets")**

and this URL is generated as a result from the redirect:

**/assets?action=show&controller=demo**

Am I missing *something* here? I thought rails was supposed to render the action's template for such cases.

Note. I understand that If I create a route like **get 'show' => "demo#show"** and call **redirect_to show_path** it'll work just fine, But I need to know if that's mandatory?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the desired behavior, use `render` instead of `redirect_to`:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render :action => "show"
  end

  def show
  end
end
```

**EDIT:**

You can use `redirect_to` on other actions, but from what I can tell, the index action sets the base path. To simplify route definition, use `resources :controller_name`. You can view the routes generated by resources by typing `rake routes` in your command line.

**Example:**

**demo_controller.rb**

```
class DemoController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def show
    redirect_to :action => 'index'
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
DispatchMe::Application.routes.draw do
  root to: "demo#index"
  resources :demo
end
```

**development.log**

```
Started GET "/demo/show" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-04 14:55:25 -0400
Processing by DemoController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"show"}
Redirected to http://dispatch.dev/
Completed 302 Found in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Yes, I was beginning to realize that myself. However to me, it seems almost unacceptable that rails doesn't permit to use redirect_to without a route definition. render works, but will not update the current URL, which isn't for this case a desired behavior. I wish someone who has large experience with RoR could explain to me why this is currently working like this.

Comment: @user766388 I've updated my answer. Let me know if you'd like a code example.

Comment: Nice, Your explanation is a lot better. But since you have offered, I can't miss the opportunity to have an example. I would really like to see it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you for the example and all the help provided Sir.